# Increase each square by random int 5-15 pixels

Tags: javascript, css, properties

Hello I have to basically change the css property of every existing square here is my code

```js
function px1() {
  var allsquares = document.querySelectorAll("#squarearea div");
  var ranpixsize = getRndInteger(5, 15);
  for (var i = 0; i < allsquares.length; i++) {
    allsquares[i].style.width = parseInt(allsquares.style.width, 10) + ranpixsize + 'px';
    allsquares[i].style.height = parseInt(allsquares.style.height, 10) + ranpixsize + 'px';
  }

}


function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<button id="colours">Change Colours</button>
```

The button is there but when I click it nothing happens to the existing squares. Any help?

Comment: Where is `px1` called?

Comment: Check your console, `allsquares.style.width` will throw an error. You probably meant `allsquares[i].style.width`

Comment: Looks like your random logic is incorrect. Also, you should use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` or something of that nature to get a `width` value. `style` properties don't always return a value.

Comment: Please tell me how my random logic is incorrect it seems fine. And Johan, took me 15 minutes to find the problem it was that. Thank you !